# XmlObject.execQuery working on OuterXml and not InnerXml

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I am trying to run some Xquery over an XML file but every time I call the xmlObject.execQuery() it goes over the OutterXml and not in the InnerXml. Let me explain, I have this XML:

```
<test><MyXml><someValues><MoreNodes>Value1</MoreNodes></someValues></MyXml></test>
```

And this is my code:

```
XmlObject inputXml = XmlObject.Factory.parse(xmlFileContent).selectChildren(new QName("test"))[0];
    paramMap.put("var1", inputXml);

    options.setXqueryVariables(paramMap);

    XmlObject[] resultsObjects = xmlObject.execQuery("declare variable $var1 as element() external; <a>{$var1/someValues/MoreNodes}</a>", options);
```

But this returns `<a/>`.

If I change the XQuery to

```
declare variable $var1 as element() external; <a>{$var1/MyXml/someValues/MoreNodes}</a>
```

Then I get the result I am expecting: `<a><MoreNodes>Value1</MoreNodes></a>`

These are only tests that I am doing, but in reality the XQuery will be read from files that are compile and running on OSB so I cannot change the XQueries content to use the correct XPath.

Any idea on how to solve my problem?

BTW if I remove the code `.selectChildren(new QName("test"))[0];` then the `xmlObject.execQuery` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple tries I figure out that I can do something like:

```
<MyXml><someValues><MoreNodes>Value1</MoreNodes></someValues></MyXml>
```

*No need to insert the parent node `<test>` that I was inserting before.

and then do something like:

```
XmlObject inputXml = XmlObject.Factory.parse(xmlFileContent).selectChildren(new QName("MyXml"))[0];
paramMap.put("var1", inputXml);

options.setXqueryVariables(paramMap);

XmlObject[] resultsObjects = xmlObject.execQuery("declare variable $var1 as element() external; <a>{$var1/someValues/MoreNodes}</a>", options);
```

and with these two changes I got what I was looking for:

```
<a><MoreNodes>Value1</MoreNodes></a>
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issue that I was facing.There isn't a lot of documentation about how to use this classes.

Thanks.